# Regex for Amazon App store URLs

Tags: ruby, regex

Here are a few examples of the Amazon urls:

```
www.amazon.com/Alawar-Entertainment-Inc-Oddly-Enough/dp/B00KRB4PFS/
www.amazon.com/dp/B00KRB4PFS/
http://www.amazon.com/Forest-Legends-The-Call-Love/dp/B00K7797FA/ref=pd_sim_mas_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=17K5ZT2ZAZM8WYAQ7NEN
```

I'm looking to write regex that extracts the product IDs from each of the urls in ruby. Any idea what the best way to write this would be?

Right now the regex that I'm thinking of using is `\/[A-Z,0-9]{10}\/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby supports `\K`. So use `\K` to ignore the matched strings,

```
dp\/\K[^\/]*
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/fQns0phq7U)

Explanation:

- `dp` matches the characters `dp` literally.
- `\/` matches the character `/` literally
- `\K` Any previously matched characters are discarded.
- `[^\/]*` Matches upto the literal `/` zero or more times.

Comment: I don't agree with the `[^\/]*` for two reasons. First, it can return empty matches. Second, there are plenty of Amazon strings without a slash after the ASIN... So if you have `amazon.com/dp/SDF555 and my dog`, you end up matching my dog. :) [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tO5uB9) That's why my solution uses specific characters, based on my experience with ASINs. You're right that `\K` is another option—you know how often I use it. Will add that as Option 2 on mine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in case-insensitive mode (as ASINs can be lower-case):

```
(?<=dp/)[A-Z0-9]+
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/zW4cR1).

**Option 2 with `\K`** to "Keep Out" what has been matched so far:

```
dp/\K[A-Z0-9]+
```

In Ruby, you need to escape the slashes:

```
if subject =~ /dp\/\K[A-Z0-9]+/i
    match = $&
```

**How this Works**

- The lookbehind `(?<=dp/)` checks that we are preceded by `dp/`... or
- `dp/\K` matches `dp/` then `\K` tells the engine to drop what has been matched so far from the match to be returned.
- `[A-Z0-9]+` matches any number of letters or digits

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: FYI, added demo and explanation. :)